# Facebook Pixel Helper doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

My Facebook Pixel Helper (Google Chrome Extensions) doesn't seem to work anymore. Whenever I look at any pixels that are installed correctly (I know because I've checked on other computers and Facebook receives the right data), I see the same error on every website.

> The Facebook pixel code on this page didn't load, so no information was sent to Facebook.

I already tried the following things:

- Quit and restart Chrome (it's also updated)
- Removed and re-installed the Pixel Helper
- Turned computer off and on again
- Searched on the Facebook Developers website and this is what it said:

> This error means that the Pixel Helper
>       found what looks to be Facebook pixel code on your site, but the
>       actual HTTP call was never made. This could typically due to an
>       error in the code, but could also occur if the pixel fires on a
>       dynamic event (e.g. on a button click).

- Searched on Google
- Extra check if the same pixels work on other computers (answer = yes)
- Emptied cache

I know there is nothing wrong with the pixels installed, but I just can’t check on my own computer - because I see that red triangle every time I use the Pixel Helper. I thought maybe this is a problem that occurs regularly and anybody here happen to know how to fix it?

Because I am fresh out of ideas :-).

Comment: _“but the actual HTTP call was never made”_ - well that could be the fault of an ad blocking/privacy extension, firewall or similar as well ... have you tried with _all other_ extensions disabled already?

Comment: Oh. My. God. You are my hero! Never figured it could be something as simple as an ad blocker.

Comment: Are you using angular ?